# Problems with Matlab function rsquare

Tags: matlab, function, data-fitting

I am calculating the coefficient of determination of my model, by doing:

```
Rsqrd1 = 1-  sum( (DataSeries(:)-ModelSeries(:)).^2 ) / sum( (DataSeries(:)-mean(ModelSeries(:) )).^2 ) ;
```

However, when I use the Matlab function below, I receive a different result (zero, that is). What could my problem be? (I don't fully understand the coding of the Matlab function and how to test it, that's why I could only compare part of it...)

```
[Rsqrd2, ~] = rsquare(DataSeries,ModelSeries);
```

FYI, below is a sample of data that I used with the following two results:

```
Rsqrd1 = 0.300314935784522;
Rsqrd2 = 0;

DataSeries = [   8.109999999999999;   7.340000000000000;   8.140000000000001;   8.529999999999999;   8.580000000000000;  10.060000000000000;  34.219999999999999;  37.899999999999999;  41.490000000000002;  41.960000000000001;  43.280000000000001;  42.950000000000003;  40.950000000000003;  41.979999999999997;  43.909999999999997;  43.250000000000000;  41.259999999999998;  49.960000000000001;  59.829999999999998;  56.850000000000001;  49.960000000000001;  39.420000000000002;  43.020000000000003;  36.509999999999998;  37.020000000000003;  35.829999999999998;  32.289999999999999;  30.079999999999998;  30.010000000000002;  28.030000000000001;  27.210000000000001;  30.460000000000001;  36.600000000000001;  38.799999999999997;  40.320000000000000;  40.530000000000001;  38.500000000000000;  36.719999999999999;  33.000000000000000;  32.009999999999998;  32.869999999999997;  40.210000000000001;  47.490000000000002;  44.950000000000003;  36.890000000000001;  34.520000000000003;  36.000000000000000;  32.289999999999999;  33.060000000000002;  29.039999999999999;  25.590000000000000;  23.340000000000000;  23.250000000000000;  24.989999999999998;  15.119999999999999;  26.010000000000002;  34.649999999999999;  36.189999999999998;  37.500000000000000;  38.560000000000002;  36.930000000000000;  33.030000000000001;  29.930000000000000;  28.390000000000001;  26.390000000000001;  33.039999999999999;  38.990000000000002;  33.930000000000000;  27.079999999999998;  18.899999999999999;  25.070000000000000;  12.250000000000000;  13.630000000000001;  15.380000000000001;  22.480000000000000;  26.090000000000000;  28.390000000000001;  31.320000000000000;  48.689999999999998;  59.969999999999999;  54.789999999999999;  44.000000000000000;  42.090000000000003;  38.390000000000001;  37.649999999999999;  32.590000000000003;  29.800000000000001;  28.649999999999999;  29.180000000000000;  34.960000000000001;  37.640000000000001;  36.939999999999998;  29.579999999999998;  26.370000000000001;  19.079999999999998;   8.789999999999999;  11.279999999999999;  10.460000000000001;   8.619999999999999;   8.770000000000000;   7.270000000000000;  20.059999999999999;  31.820000000000000;  39.460000000000001;  38.840000000000003;  38.520000000000003;  38.039999999999999;  33.590000000000003;  32.979999999999997;  32.960000000000001;  36.640000000000001;  38.119999999999997;  39.549999999999997;  46.990000000000002;  58.469999999999999;  54.539999999999999;  39.770000000000003;  37.560000000000002;  39.259999999999998;  32.049999999999997;  34.729999999999997;  34.630000000000003;  31.260000000000002;  30.039999999999999;  30.280000000000001;  31.890000000000001;  41.670000000000002;  59.890000000000001;  59.890000000000001;  59.329999999999998;  58.409999999999997;  59.090000000000003;  55.969999999999999;  53.520000000000003;  49.939999999999998;  47.289999999999999;  47.570000000000000;  55.899999999999999;  59.939999999999998;  59.240000000000002;  52.939999999999998;  38.329999999999998;  36.710000000000001;  35.460000000000001;  35.810000000000002;  34.840000000000003;  33.259999999999998;  32.590000000000003;  33.259999999999998;  34.090000000000003;  44.939999999999998;  59.430000000000000;  58.270000000000003;  58.270000000000003;  58.270000000000003;  58.079999999999998;  56.039999999999999;  55.430000000000000;  53.950000000000003;  53.439999999999998;  51.969999999999999;  58.880000000000003;  82.299999999999997;  70.109999999999999;  62.310000000000002;  51.930000000000000;  45.950000000000003;  37.549999999999997];

ModelSeries = [   8.109999999999998;   8.033959427220921;   8.323743041322626;   8.642708281120481;   8.582517975760446;  11.267851534695547;  19.265627892290375;  24.383823505293059;  24.255451695071979;  23.221588621286294;  23.061055862798810;  22.113019289306415;  21.371289863159902;  20.649139051697372;  20.517347467041816;  20.204389732885463;  20.152889919509455;  23.796341860624523;  28.357685405641778;  26.637620279541537;  22.250623983516938;  18.521786633703048;  17.231002075227554;  13.067216036414376;  19.142739022137061;  17.721978391048754;  15.855447009714094;  14.671720684372842;  14.681919810093815;  14.765381876692128;  11.357099766936273;  15.816337667523761;  20.080445840613475;  21.201625338935443;  22.073981571269272;  22.515202276491678;  21.543798733221458;  19.960000354644297;  18.067072108251327;  17.381842068691483;  17.031516337275718;  21.137586012909246;  25.023728337649139;  22.772401470260085;  18.479087827412922;  14.972363725126110;  17.654172434932196;  11.716255484871617;  19.715961876585990;  18.155212284709371;  16.157517128358631;  14.873595374529506;  14.807724678847782;  14.816736894019828;  11.339910137512746;  15.714998343157673;  19.855463769222808;  20.864416383513849;  21.621229985316365;  21.951821367820752;  20.909538825844994;  19.286028051295396;  17.380523953397315;  16.649325149265788;  16.244747678122277;  20.077382742947545;  23.671685948867548;  21.455816819780182;  17.342414495551786;  13.997360909813795;  16.442356118812683;  10.871782060716438;   9.254066806706989;   9.020435845559256;   9.198343907518664;   9.402433405571619;   9.194123813724323;  11.889052472788039;  20.026481568965160;  24.977165077948360;  24.489207826870764;  23.114540096244365;  22.636235398768406;  21.409588152343272;  20.414075626818608;  19.464490741778725;  19.090081921322344;  18.560137046203984;  18.282057191300733;  21.323265914583974;  25.105779337411779;  23.305664987061846;  19.243112642200309;  15.837518714974767;  14.571028978312411;  10.930566921047774;   8.043061483121409;   7.828278448844956;   7.971443209965454;   8.137571402681322;   7.947505847139930;  10.477597371114410;  17.994873577687876;  22.884932423902036;  22.880903074120706;  22.024300523218443;  21.996973699650383;  21.219211759187829;  20.636217357395591;  20.069520890245851;  20.077349735794858;  19.910967044646512;  20.005696385024002;  23.801346418078619;  28.585076924647108;  27.067028838815997;  22.796087957505328;  19.136718350436571;  17.957761530043999;  13.739457493789578;  10.310824888906227;  10.234357169105408;  10.627415478755154;  11.062492850356721;  11.016017242485642;  14.506641643689173;  24.884595907986515;  31.606278720197437;  31.557624279398006;  30.332367155586006;  30.248647555318538;  29.132457008298452;  28.284532096511711;  27.459546453686421;  27.419960762893837;  27.140870313592835;  27.215931128615544;  32.312946353894560;  38.724658154432746;  36.587267960523683;  30.743914731877290;  25.748050465465422;  24.103274970768545;  18.395418569792440;  13.769537490600122;  13.631459113517636;  14.116779371574737;  14.654058009734536;  14.551159058407341;  19.106427552870549;  32.677949691257076;  41.379150497789212;  41.187871023605659;  39.464033938070862;  39.228799119138912;  37.657741343154058;  36.440049352143852;  35.257483623102601;  35.085564440852409;  34.607106722839973;  34.579707730445875;  40.908025648164319;  48.846243022607112;  45.979419502968788;  38.491201346114494;  32.114034660484577;  29.947100964693604;  22.766547766228452];
```

Comment: `rsquare` does not seem to be a default matlab function, did you used [this implementation](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34492-r-square--the-coefficient-of-determination)?

Comment: Yes, and I added some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having some data would help in identifying the issue.
Are you referring to the Matlab function posted [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34492-r-square--the-coefficient-of-determination)?

If yes, in the posted example it would seem it would work with row-vectors. Maybe that could be the issue (?) I do not have access to Matlab, but possibly this might work:

rsquareColumnTest = @(x,y) rsquare( (x(:).') , (y(:).') );

and then Rsqrd2 =  rsquareColumnTest(DataSeries,ModelSeries);

If it passes the test, of course, feel free to pass the transpose of your data directly, without the need of defining the anonymous function.

*Further editing after having received the data*

Thanks for providing the data.

First: R^2 is generally not a good idea you may want to have a look [at this site](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/rsquared.htm), for example.

That said, R^2 makes sense if you want to compare how a linear model is doing with respect to a constant model. A constant model is a subset of a linear model, that is why R^2 can never be negative (or should never be negative, if used properly).

If you look at the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) you define R^2 as

```
Rsqrd1 = 1 - sumSqDiff(DataSeries, ModelSeries) / sumSqDiff(DataSeries, mean(ModelSeries));
```

where I have defined

```
sumSqDiff = @(x,y)  sum( (x(:)-y(:)).^2 );
```

According to the definition of R^2 (and I encourage you to see why), you should use:

```
Rsqrd1 = 1-sumSqDiff(DataSeries, ModelSeries) / sumSqDiff(DataSeries, mean(DataSeries);
```

if you do that you have Rsqrd1 = -0.6791;
that makes no sense, since R^2 is between 0 and 1, but it is possible since your model is not a linear model (does not contain the constant model, as a subset). The rsquare function you have found on the web takes this into account and cap it at 0, specifically it says

```
r2 = max(0,1 - sum((y(:)-f(:)).^2)/sum((y(:)-mean(y(:))).^2));
```

since r2 is negative, you have 0 as result. You can use that very function taking into account that you have no constant term in your model, calling it 
rsquare(DataSeries,ModelSeries, false) (if you look into documentation it refers to this case).

Again, I would encourage you not to use R^2 especially in this case, but I hope I have clarified why you are having a different result.

Comment: Yes, that is the function I refer to. The main calculation is the same, but I don't understand the different conditions...  Unfortunately the transpose test doesn't do it. Any other suggestions??   Let me play around with the data a bit more, and I can post a data example later.

Comment: Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry I forgot. I will look into that later.

Comment: Hi LenaH, I have looked into your code and rsquare code, as promised. I will edit my answer for completeness

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I feel bad that I didn't see the typo in my equation :-( Thank you also for the additional info.